# Why is put null, when finding max value using math.max

Tags: javascript

I cant understand the reason to put null when finding max value.

```
<script>
    var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myArrayMax(points);

    function myArrayMax(arr) {
      return Math.max.apply(null, arr);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: when using apply, first argument is a value for `this` - it's in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), `Function.apply()` takes two arguments, named `thisArg` and `argsArray`.

`thisArg` is the value that the keyword `this` will refer to in the function. For `Math.max`, which is effectively a static function (it doesn't depend on any instance or stateful information), `this` is not used at all. So, the value doesn't matter.

The reason `null` is passed is so that the second argument can be given a value, as you can't have a second argument without a first. In this case, the second argument is an array of arguments given to `Math.max()`. The statement :

```
Math.max.apply(null, arr);
```

is effectively shorthand for `Math.max(arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],...,arr[arr.length-1])`, i.e. passing the elements of the array as arguments to the function.

Note that as per Mister Jojo's answer, that is basically a polyfill for the spread operator of ES6+. The above snippet can be accomplished just as easily, and to many in a more readable fashion, with:

```
Math.max(...arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

the apply method that help to use prototype method directly requires `this` to bind with itself. and real required parameter should be passed as wrapped with `[]`.

For example,

```js
function MyObject() {
};

MyObject.prototype.printProp = function(){
  for(let key in this){
    console.log(key, this[key]);
  }
}

MyObject.prototype.printProp.apply({value : 10}, []);
```

in example above, if you want apply `printProp` function to your own object `{value : 10}` it is not a instance of `MyObject`.

Then, just pass this object to first parameter of apply function to bind it as this inside myFunction.

in your case, `Math.max` function don't require any object to bind as this inside function. so, you just pass null as first parameter and number list as second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, `Math.max.apply(this, arr);` will also works because I think the **Math.max** method does not really use this or the this has not real impact.

But if a function do use significantly the **context**, therefore you should be aware of the first parameters (which is usually **thisArg**) because it might have a side behaviour